# Desktop icon for calling a Python script does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, desktop, shortcut

I'm trying to execute this desktop shortcut, but it doesn't work. The paths are right.

However, despite having indicated the image to associate with the icon, clicking on it does not launch the python script and the image is not associated. Therefore the classic gear image appears. If I click on it, the text file simply opens.

Help to solve this problem?

Here the code:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name= Launcher 
Version=1.0
Icon=/home/workstation/Desktop/launcher/icon_launcher.png

Path=/home/workstation/Desktop/launcher
Exec=python3 Launcher.py
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name[it_IT]= Launcher_test
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to need to add what error you are getting but I think it is syntax. Here is the updated version.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name = 'Launcher'
Version = 1.0
Icon = r'/home/workstation/Desktop/launcher/icon_launcher.png'

Path = r'/home/workstation/Desktop/launcher'
Exec = python3 Launcher.py
StartupNotify = True
Terminal = False
Type = Application
Name[it_IT] = 'Launcher_test'
```

Let me know if this works. There are a few ways of implementing it.

Comment: Unfortunately It doesn't work. Then some icon desktop disappear when I move the shortcut on the desktop. My ubuntu version is 20.04

Comment: @TforV You are using Ubuntu so that changes a lot. Remove the r from the quotes and see what happens.

Comment: unfortunately the same.....I don't know why...on ubuntu 18.04 it worked....this version is still a problem :(

Comment: It may not be the code, I think it is the OS. Because newer versions are always buggy. I use Windows so I do not now much of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is completely wrong and the actual solution from the OP can be found in the rejected edit of that answer.

### From the OP's edit

---

I think that is a problem of the default desktop of Ubuntu 20.04.

So I decided to try something different. I installed Gnome Vanilla on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Focal Fossa

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-session gdm3
```

then

```
$ sudo reboot
```

But...being Vanilla very basic...I decided to install Full Gnome Desktop on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Focal Fossa with

first

```
$ sudo apt install tasksel
```

second

```
$ sudo tasksel install ubuntu-desktop
```

then

```
$ sudo reboot
```

and so it works.

I saw the procedure here https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-gnome-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-al-fossa